# git-number not working on Linux: sh: git-id: not found

Tags: linux, bash, git

I've set up the script [git-number](https://github.com/holygeek/git-number) on my Cygwin computer without any problems. I've put all three required scripts in a folder in my home directory called bin/ and everything works fine. Now I'm trying to set it up on an Amazon EC2 instance, and I'm running into problems. When I run `git number` on the EC2 machine, I get

`sh: /home/gulshan/bin/git-id: not found`

Any idea what could be wrong?

EDIT: Directory listing of ~/bin

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gulshan gulshan 1.5K 2012-03-17 06:01 git-id
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gulshan gulshan 4.7K 2012-03-17 06:02 git-list
-rwxr-xr-x 1 gulshan gulshan 2.2K 2012-03-17 06:07 git-number
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the `/home/gulshan/bin/git-id` file executable?  Please add the directory listing of `/home/gulshan/bin/` if this does not solve the problem.

Comment: I've added the listing to the answer. Everything is executable.